# FusionCharts 3.3.1 - escape label and tooltip

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I have FusionCharts 3.3.1-sr2.19840 . How do I escape tooltips for html code? If I have an `<input>` in tooltip or even a `<script>` with some alert in it, it will trigger my JavaScript code... this is a huge problem. Is there a property to escape tooltips and labels?

Here is a print screen with the tooltip unescaped:

[image]

Comment: @NBhargav Code for what? Basically, what I'm asking is for a way to escapeHtml the labels and tooltips

Comment: Do you mean that you are passing xml/json data having JS code in toolText and it is getting executed? If yes, that's very unlikely. If no, then you would need to elaborate further or post erring use-case with code sample.

Comment: @ShamasisBhattacharya Yes, it is possible... for example: I have a json with school names sent from server and I want to show a graph with number of users from every school and let's say the name of one of the schools is " School1 <input type='text' /> ", in the interface/graph it will show that input. I want to restrict this thing. I use FusionCharts 3.3.1-sr2.19840

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "& lt;" and "& gt;" to escape the tag. I have created a fiddle to solve the problem. 
http://jsfiddle.net/subramaniashiva/4jgfeejx/

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
var ageGroupChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'pie3d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '450',
    height: '300',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
        "chart": {
            "caption": "Split of Visitors by Age Group",
                "subCaption": "Last year",
                "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#f2c500,#f45b00,#8e0000",
                "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                "showBorder": "0",
                "use3DLighting": "0",
                "showShadow": "0",
                "enableSmartLabels": "0",
                "startingAngle": "0",
                "showPercentValues": "1",
                "showPercentInTooltip": "0",
                "decimals": "1",
                "captionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                "toolTipColor": "#ffffff",
                "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
                "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
                "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
                "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
                "toolTipPadding": "5",
                "showHoverEffect": "1",
                "showLegend": "1",
                "legendBgColor": "#ffffff",
                "legendBorderAlpha": '0',
                "legendShadow": '0',
                "legendItemFontSize": '10',
                "legendItemFontColor": '#666666'
        },
            "data": [{
            "label": "Teenage",
                "value": "1250400",
                "tooltext": "&lt;input type=\"text\"&gt; Teenage"
        }, {
            "label": "Adult",
                "value": "1463300",
                "tooltext": "&lt;input type=\"text\"&gt; Adult"
        }, {
            "label": "Mid-age",
                "value": "1050700",
                "tooltext": "&lt;input type=\"text\"&gt; Mid-age"
        }, {
            "label": "Senior",
                "value": "491000",
                "tooltext": "&lt;input type=\"text\"&gt; Senior"
        }]
    }
}).render();
});
```